# Проблема с PyQt4 QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Добрый день! При попытках разобраться с PyQt возникла проблема. 
Есть следующий код:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __imit__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.resize(450,250)
        self.setWindowTitle('menubar')

        exit = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('icons/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.connect(exit, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), QtCore.SLOT('close()'))

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        file.addAction(exit)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Почему-то при выполнении появляется просто виджет явно меньшего размера с заголовком "python". Не подскажете, в чём ошибка?

Comment: А, всё, вопрос снят, у меня __imit__ вместо __init__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что вы видите в этой строчке ?

`def __imit__(self):`

ни чего не замечаете?